# Вылавливание событий в Discord | Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Можно ли как-то вылавливать событие клика на определённое сообщение (тег)? Если да, то как это сделать? Возможно ли это?

Comment: Вы можете отследить нажатие кнопки по сообщению, но только если сообщение было отправлено вашим ботом. Для этого есть событие `on_button_click`, принимающая один параметр, `type` которого - `MessageInteraction`.
*Использовалась библиотека `disnake` версии 2.2.2

Answer (score 0):

Такое событие невозможно отследить, а список событий которые возможно отследить есть в [документации Discord](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#commands-and-events)